# Content-Security-Policy does not work although I use a wildcard

Tags: cordova, meteor, cordova-plugins, content-security-policy

In my Meteor/Cordova project, the user can upload an image. This image is then uploaded to a cloud service. But before, I already want to display the uploaded image to the user. Immediately! So I take the cdvfile-Url and set it as the `<img>`s "src". For example:

```html
<img src="cdvfile://localhost/root/storage/emulated/0/x/y.jpg" />
```

My CSP meta Tag looks like this:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; img-src *">
```

Unfortunately, this is what I get as a result, although the meta tag is not very restrictive:

> Refused to load the image
>   'cdvfile://localhost/root/storage/emulated/0/x/y.jpg' because it
>   violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src *".

I have tried a huge number of variations of the CSP Meta Tag with no luck.  I have tried with and without `cordova-plugin-whitelist`. Anybody who has a clue and can help?

Thanks

Comment: What happens when adding a slash before the star in the content attribute?

Comment: Does not work. It just leads to much more errors: "The source list for Content Security Policy directive 'img-src' contains an invalid source: '/*'. It will be ignored."

Answer (score 4):

You need to explicitly specify `cdvfile:` in the policy, like this:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
    content="default-src *; img-src * cdvfile:">
```

The reason is that per [requirements in the CSP spec](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#match-url-to-source-expression), the `*` wildcard only matches URLs with a “network scheme”, which is defined as [“a scheme that is "`ftp`" or an HTTP(S) scheme”](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#network-scheme).

So in general, any time you want to make a CSP policy allow a resource with a URL with a protocol part that’s not `https`, `http`, or `ftp`, then you must explicitly specify the protocol in your policy.

Comment: I had tried that before but unfortunately, this results in this error message: Refused to load the image 'cdvfile://localhost/root/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20180315_150821.jpg' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src * gap: data: blob: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' ws: wss:". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Comment: BTW: I had to change your proposed meta tag to: <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline'; img-src * cdvfile:"> Otherwise, my scripts wouldn't run at all

Comment: That’s not “my” proposed meta tag — it’s your meta tag from the question exactly as-is, with only the addition of cdvfile: to the img-src directive, which has no effect on whether scripts run or not. So what you’re saying is that your CSP policy in the meta tag in the question actually doesn’t work unless you add 'unsafe-inline' to it. That’s a completely different problem than the one that caused the error message cited in the question. And the fix for that error in fact really is what this answer says to do: You must add cdvfile: to the img-src directive.

Comment: As far as the error *“because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src * gap: data: blob: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' ws: wss:". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.”* that’s not caused by adding cdvfile: to the img-src directive. As the message indicates, that indicates you’re using a policy that doesn’t even have an img-src directive at all. But the policy in the answer has an img-src directive. So if you manage to put in img-src directive with cdvfile: in your actual policy, it in fact really will work.

Comment: The only ways I can image that you would have caused that *“because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src * gap: data: blob: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' ws: wss:"* message is iehter by serving your document with a Content-Security-Policy HTTP header that has a different value than your meta element shown in the question, or by putting into the document an additional meta element with a different policy. Regardless, that message would never by caused by the policy shown in the answer here.